# Number of Cells which have a specific text, but where the row also has another specific text

Tags: google-sheets, microsoft-excel

There are some WoW terms in this post, will clarify if requested.

I'm making a spreadsheet in google sheets for my wow guild where we will be able to input our class, spec and if it is an alt or not.

The input part is done, but I also want to automatically showcase how many of each role we have and how many of those are alts.

So you get one row per character, where you input name, class, spec, gear, off-spec, off-spec gear and if it is an alt.

Let's say the only inputed character is a Protection Paladin, with Holy Off-spec and it is an alt. I then want the showcase to show that we have one alt Tank and one Alt Off-Spec Healer.

It's the alt part that gets me. Using an ifcounts I can check how many tanks, healers, ranged DPS and Melee DPS we have. But I want it to sort into whether or not the Alt section is on Yes or No. So for each row it checks the spec, off-spec and if it is an alt or not. Then counts the character accordingly.

This might be confusing to read, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: start by using the `filter()` function

Comment: And then? Not sure how that works

Comment: Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel are not identical, choose one. Also show what you tried showing some sample data directly in the question body and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Welcome to WebApps. Your question must stand on its own. WOW is irrelevant, per se; you need to explain your data and relationships between your data. For example: "with Holy Off-spec and it is an alt... the showcase to show that we have one alt Tank and one Alt Off-Spec Healer." If this Paladin is an "alt", then how/where does your data specifically define the relationships with the various alt types. Would you please edit your question to provide some sample data, explain how the relationships are established, and provide an example of how a successful outcome would be displayed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.